# Boyer-Moore string search algorithm run time complexity

Tags: string, algorithm, pattern-matching, boyer-moore

In [Boyer-Moore string search algorithm wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm)  link, it is stated that worst case complexity of Boyer-Moore is

1. ***O(m+n)*** if pattern does not appear in the text
2. ***O(mn)*** if pattern does appear in the text

But in [String Search Algorithm wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm), it is stated that worst case complexity of Boyer-Moore is ***O(n)***. Why is this disparity ?

[Here](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~lecroq/string/node14.html) also it is stated to be O(mn) in worst case.

So what is the correct run time complexity of Boyer-Moore algorithm ?

Comment: at least consistently spell it!

Comment: also the first link table where you quote "it is stated that worst case complexity of Boyer-Moore is O(n). " has 2 columns....which are not meant to be taken separately...

Answer (score 2):

The difference comes from different definitions. In the general string search page, algorithms complexity is split to preprocessing and matching, whereas the page for the algorithm itself didn't make that distinction.

The preprocessing will be Θ(m + k) plus O(n) for matching.

Comment: What is k there?